# Can't find or load main class JarSplice

Tags: java, class, path, program-entry-point

Hello fellow programmers! I am writing a game at the moment, that uses the following libraries: LWJGL, OpenGL, Slick. I know the problems with simply exporting a JAR file from eclipse when using libraries like that, and I do use the JarSplice program to make a fat JAR. This has worked fine for about a month now, however, just recently it stopped working. Whenever I export the JAR from eclipse, and make it a fat JAR using JarSplice, I get this error:

```
Could not find or load main class Game.jar
```

**META-INF (Located in the fat JAR):**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Launcher-VM-Args: 
Launcher-Main-Class: cubix.main.Cubix
Main-Class: org.ninjacave.jarsplice.JarSpliceLauncher
```

Please note that the main method of the program is located in the Cubix.class, which is located in cubix.main.Cubix'

I have never came across this error before, and it is driving me insane. If any additional information is required, please feel free to ask.

EDIT:
I might also add that if I export any other project this way (using the same libraries and using jarsplice to build a fat JAR) it works just fine. I am only experiencing this problem with this specific project in eclipse. However, when I run Cubix in eclipse debugger, it runs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try couple of things :1 check the content of the file, use jar -tf see everything is present2. can you try running this file from command/terminal.3 if all above is good, compile Cubix.java from terminal and place this .class file in jar file manually and check.

Comment: Trial of the third and second options gave me the same error still. And on the first option, what do you mean by "use jar -tf"?

Comment: Can you try running Cubix.class from terminal(java Cubix) and also run jar -tf jatFileName.jar from terminal and paste the output here?

Comment: I tried running Cubix.class from the terminal with no success. And when I ran 'jar -tf Game.jar'(or at least I think that's what you mean) it said 'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Maybe i'm not doing something right?

Comment: How can it be possible that you are not able to run java Cubix ? can you set the path variable, once set jar command would be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for posting this. The problem wasn't that it couldn't find the main class but rather I had typed the command line wrong. I typed: 'java Cubix.jar -jar' rather than 'java -jar Cubix.jar'. Also, after fixing the command line, it gave me the stack trace for the error that was overlooked by eclipse, and that one of the textures that needed to be loaded was case sensitive.